# Resetting password

Tags: password, password-recovery

I really need help my cousin changed root password of Ubuntu based compute *please note that it was done months ago and I didn't face any problem at that time..* But now that I'm trying to run applications and use terminal i don't know the password and my cousin forgot it too... I have to add some features to my computer which is why unlocking administrator is necessary.. Can someone help with changing password or resetting computer to it's initial state...
I have tried my best but most of the time the program asks for the primary password which has been forgotten.

Comment: Ubuntu has the *root* user disabled by default; so changing that password should not impact a Ubuntu user at all; as their `sudo` password is their own password & not the *root* password. What you describe shouldn't impact a Ubuntu system, use your normal account and use `sudo passwd root` to change the *root* password to something you know.  What exactly do you mean by "*Ubuntu based*" as specific details are needed for us to understand your situation; what you describe shouldn't stop a Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server user.

Comment: A few months ago I was kind of addicted to upgrading my computer and my cousin changed the admin password  thanks for the information i am trying it rn! *Btw i dont know the root password and the terminal is keep asking me for it.. and my main password is actually just a space bar it's kind of not working....

Comment: When you login to a text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4 for example), the system should report what it is...   Details of your software stack (ie. what OS & release you're using, "*Ubuntu based*" isn't helpful as too vague) are most useful in us providing you with useful advice.  Defaults change over time, and without release, we don't know what *defaults* you're using.

Comment: If you're being asked for a *root* password; you're not using a Ubuntu system most likely; so I'd try and examine what you're using, as Ubuntu will ask for the password for the $USERNAME that was setup during install (*which won't be root as that is disabled*)   FYI:  Other GNU/Linux systems (eg. OpenSuSE) will ask for a *root* password; Ubuntu cannot as that account is *disabled* by default and no password is thus acceptable.

Comment: "terminal is keep asking me for it"? Are you booted into Ubuntu (did you see the Ubuntu logo or verbose boot yet), or are you at the BIOS' password screen? Otherwise, stop using `su` and start using `sudo -i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: @guiverc sir thanks for the support because after few time the sudo root password worked and my pc is brand new